# Regex expression to select file name with 2 dots from file list

Tags: java, regex

I need a **regex** expression that will select files with particular file name format from the file list of zip files.
I need to select files with file names with following file format:

```
<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char>.<A-Z/a-z/0-9/special char>.zip
```

The file name contains 2 dots `.` and it can be any string between the dots `.`
for examples, following are **valid** file names that can be selected:

```
abc123.34efg.zip
qwe.123.zip
as_2ww.as_tyy.zip
23.fff.zip
asd.efg.zip
```

It can be **letter** or **number** or **special char** or **combination** **between** them, between the dots `.`
Please note that it can be **only 2 dots** `.` in the file name.
Anything other than 2 dots `.` is not a valid file name and will not be selected.

Following are **invalid** file name:

```
abc.zip
abc.123.efg.zip
as_1.efg.ddd.rr.zip
ee_rr.zip
```

I tried following regex:

```
[^.]*\\.[^.].zip
```

but not working. Maybe this is wrong.
Please let me know the correct regex expression to select the required file name

Comment: only a single character between the dots, or missing the `*`? Also likely missing backslashes for last point...

Comment: you probably want this `[^.]*\\.[^.]*\\.zip `

Comment: I dont think my previous comment would workm I think following would work `[^\\.]+\\.[^\\.]+\\.zip`

Comment: Format is `<any string including number or/and sp char>.<any string including number or/and sp char>.zip`

Comment: The regex is inside a string? Can you try my answer? I think it works now. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this (I put double backslashes assuming your regex is inside a Java string.):

```
^[^.]+\\.[^.]+\\.zip$
```

Also, a good alternative pointed by [Xirema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5241642/xirema)

```
^(?:[^.]+\\.){2}zip$)
```

I tested it in this [website](https://regex101.com/). With this input:

```
abc123.34efg.zip
qwe.123.zip
as_2ww.as_tyy.zip
23.fff.zip
asd.efg.zip
abc.zip
abc.123.efg.zip
as_1.efg.ddd.rr.zip
ee_rr.zip
```

Also tested with this input (thanks to [Matt.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9534819/matt-g))

```
..zip
a..zip
.a.zip
```

Comment: it allows these invalid values `..zip` `.a.zip` `a..zip`

Comment: You could reduce it to `^(?:[^\.]+\.){2}zip$` (or, with the backslashes escaped, `^(?:[^\\.]+\\.){2}zip$`), which has the benefit of being easier to extend if the user decides they want exactly 3 or 4 dots instead of exactly 2.